# how to make sure that flink job has finished executing and then perform some tasks

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to perform some tasks after flink job is completed,I am not having any issues when I run code in Intellij but there are isssues when I run Flink jar in a shell file. I am using below line to make sure that execution of flink program is complete

```
//start the execution

JobExecutionResult jobExecutionResult = envrionment.execute(" Started the execution ");

 is_job_finished = jobExecutionResult.isJobExecutionResult();
```

**I am not sure, if above check is correct or not ?**

Then I am using the above varible in below method to perform some tasks

```
    if(print_mode && is_job_finished){



        System.out.println(" \n \n -- System related  variables  -- \n");

        System.out.println(" Stream_join Window length = " + WindowLength_join__ms + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println(" Input rate for stream RR  = " + input_rate_rr_S + " events/second");
        System.out.println("Stream RR Runtime = " + Stream_RR_RunTime_S + " seconds");
        System.out.println(" # raw events in stream RR  = " + Total_Number_Of_Events_in_RR + "\n");

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: hi, could you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a job listener to execution environment.

For example

```
env.registerJobListener(new JobListener {
      //Callback on job submission.
      override def onJobSubmitted(jobClient: JobClient, throwable: Throwable): Unit = {
        if (throwable == null) {
          log.info("SUBMIT SUCCESS")
        } else {
          log.info("FAIL")
        }
      }
    //Callback on job execution finished, successfully or unsuccessfully.
      override def onJobExecuted(jobExecutionResult: JobExecutionResult, throwable: Throwable): Unit = {

        if (throwable == null) {
          log.info("SUCCESS")
        } else {
          log.info("FAIL")
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a [JobListener](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/core/execution/JobListener.html) to your StreamExecutionEnvironment.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to do it ?

Comment: mstzn includes an example in scala. You can see more at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.11/flink-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/test/execution/JobListenerITCase.java

Comment: My comment was to make your answer more helpful, simply directing to documentation may not be enough for the one asking the question to solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

JobListener is grate program if not SQL API.

if use SQL API, onJobExecuted will never be called. I have a idea, you can refer to it. the source is Kafka, sink can use any type.
[image]

let me explain it :

- EndSign: follow to last data. when your Flink job consumed it, meaning the partition element rest is empty.

Close loigcal:

- When you flink job processing EndSign. job need to call JobController, then JobController counter +1
- Until the JobController counter equals partition count. then JobController will check consumer group lag, ensure Flink job get all data.
- Now, we know the job is finished